# Retreive element from PhP array

Tags: php, postgresql

I am getting data from database in PhP array **data_areas** like this:

```
$query_area = "SELECT name FROM area where id>0";
$result = pg_query($con, $query_area) or die("Cannot execute query: $query_area\n");

if(pg_num_rows($result))
{
     $data_areas=array();
     while($row=pg_fetch_row($result))
     { 
           $data_areas[] = array(
           'name'=>$row[0]
           );
     }         
     pg_free_result($result);
     pg_close($con);

     $area1=$data_areas[0];
     $area2=$data_areas[1];         
    }
```

How to retrieve the element from array in different variables, for example, I tried to retrieve data in area1 and area2 variable. Thank you

Comment: So it should work. What's wrong?

Comment: I was trying to get the value of array. I go it through: $data_areas[0]['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this;

```
$data_areas[0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
$query_area = "SELECT name FROM area where id>0";
$result = pg_query($con, $query_area) or die("Cannot execute query: $query_area\n");

if(pg_num_rows($result))
{
     $data_areas=array();
     while($row=pg_fetch_row($result))
     { 
           $data_areas[] = array(
           'name'=>$row[0]
           );
     }         
     pg_free_result($result);
     pg_close($con);

     $area1=isset($data_areas[0]['name']) ?$data_areas[0]['name'] : '' ;
     $area2= isset($data_areas[1]['name']) ? $data_areas[1]['name'] : '';         
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This idea is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So first things first. You need first of all set up your array that you retrieve your data from the db.

Inside your while loop , and considering that you know what each of the rows has as associated value you can do something like:

```
$data_areas[] = array(
    'name' => $row[0],
    'surname' => $row[1],
    'email' => $row[2]
);
```

This will create your array with all the values.

Now if you want to access/assign it's of those array values i am pretty sure you will need new dedicated arrays as your query retrieves all data from the table (small note that you don't need `where id>0` as your id is auto increment so it will always be greater than 0)

Having said that we can move forward.

In order to access this data you can simple try:

```
print_r($data_areas['name']);
```

This will return you an array of all the names you have. So you don't need new table you can use the already existing one you have.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me alot to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing like this
`$row[0]`
Try writing this
`$row['name']`